# access first letter of a string in a set c++

Tags: c++, string, iterator, set

I have a set of strings and I need to access each one and compare the first letter of the string to a char and stop if they are the same. How do I go through that? I tried with

```
char* p;

for (std::set<string>::iterator iter=myset.begin(); iter!=myset.end();iter++)
    {p = *iter;
    if (p==characterForComparison) return 0;
    }
```

but that does not pass the compiler, it says

```
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'char *'
```

How do I solve this? What I need is fairly simple, so I need as simple a solution as I can get, just go through all the strings, compare the first letter, and if they are the same, return 0;

Comment: Is characterForComparison a char * or a single char? The error says char *

Comment: The dereferenced iterator (\*iter) points to an std::string and not an char* therefore you can not assign std::string to char*. Try something like: char p = (\*iter)[0].

Answer (score 5):

To compare first character of `std::string` just do:

```
if (!(*iter).empty() && 
    (*iter)[0] == characterForComparison)
{
}
```

To access first element in a string, string provides `operator[]`, `front()`, or use `begin` to get reference to first element. see [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) page.

Comment: @WhozCraig What's amazing is that no one else seems to have used it.  It should be automatic.  (And of course, you could also write `iter->front() == characterForComparison` after the test for empty, at least in C++11, or `*iter->begin() == characterForComparison`.

Answer (score 2):

Since your set contains `std::string`s, dereferencing the iterator gives you a `string`, not its first character. Use operator `[]` instead:

```
p = (*iter)[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

`*iter` is a string, try

```
char p;
//...
p = (*iter)[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems. The first is that you try to assign a `std::string` object to a `char*`. The second is if you want the first character, then `p` should be declared as a character and not a pointer to a character.

And of course, there's really no need to store the character in a temporary variable like `p`, at least not in such a simple case such as yours. Use it directly from the string like

```
if ((*iter)[0] == characterForComparison) { /* do something */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

if you can use C++11:

```
for(auto s : myset)
{
  if(s[0] == characterForComparison)
  {
     return 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A C++ string is not convertible to a C-style string. `*iter` gives you a C++ string.

If you want to actually compare the first character of a string, then.

```
if ((*iter)[0] == 'a')
```

would do the trick.

If you actually need a `const char *`, you can use:

```
p = iter->c_str();
```

Note however that this is a CONSTANT string, you shouldn't modify it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the STL algorithms.
If you can use C++11:

```
bool set_condition(const char c, const set<string>& s)
{
    auto position = 
        find_if(s.cbegin(), s.cend(), [c](const string& s) { return s[0] == c; } );


    return (position != s.cend() ); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try to wrap the char in an instance of std:string:

```
std:string comp(characterForComparison);
```

and

retrieve the first character with [0]

Comment: Why wrap the character in a string?

Comment: @interjay to take it right back out (see the last line in the answer?) =P